# Passando lista array por paramêtro

Tags: c#, array, web-service

Estou com o seguinte problema:

Preciso passar alguns arquivos (xmls e pdf) de minha aplicação winforms para um webservice.

O problema é que não é possível passar via parâmetros para um WS tipo de dados como List<>.

Nesse caso, vou fazer com que seja passado array contendo os bytes do arquivo, para que eu possa renderizá-lo no servidor dentro do WS.

Estou com dificuldade para enviar e receber essa lista através de uma lista.

```
// Cada arquivo eu insiro em um List<byte[]>, exemplo:
listaDeBytes.Add(File.ReadAllBytes(arrayAnexos[x]));
```

Nesse caso, eu tenho em minha lista 3 registros com seus respectivos bytes dentro.
Para transformar essa lista em array, faço o seguinte:

```
// Transformando a List<byte[]> em uma array de byte:
byte[] listaEmByte = listaDeBytes.SelectMany(a => a).ToArray();
```

Nesse momento, ele inseriu os 3 registros com seus bytes nesse array, porém parece ter juntado tudo.
O problema é como interpretar essa listaEmByte que recebo em meu WS. Como transformá-la novamente em uma lista de bytes para eu fazer a leitura da mesma.

Tentei transformá-lo em um byte[][], porém não é possível fazer a conversão de lista para byte[][] através do SelectMany.

Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda.
Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sintaxe para converter sua lista de array de bytes para um array de bytes bidimensional deve ser esta:

```
byte[][] listaEmByte = listaDeBytes.SelectMany(a => new byte[][]{a}).ToArray();
```

Ou se quiser remover código redundante, podemos tirar a parte que cria o array explicitamente.

```
byte[][] listaEmByte = listaDeBytes.SelectMany(a => new[] { a }).ToArray();
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Murari. Realmente dessa forma transformou em bidimensional. E isso solucionou o problema! Agradeço pela ajuda =)